# How to list remote branch without web request?

Tags: git, branch, git-remote

i just want to list my local remote branches. but when i run `git remote show origin`, it needs to take a request to the server. How can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git branch -r`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) will list all remote-tracking branches that exist in your local repository:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

You can also use the `-a` option to get all branches that exist in your local repository:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-a` option to `git branch` will list all remote-tracking branches. This is mentioned in the manual page.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above.

```
git branch -a
```

will display all your branches.

#### Important:

`git branch -a` will indeed display the list of branches but those are the branched currently tracked under your `.git` folder. As a best practice you should update your `.git` folder before listing the branches.

The update is done using the `git fetch --all --prune`

The `--all` will update all the branches and tags.
The `--prune` will remove all the deleted branches.